# Laravel loading pilymorphic related model with main model not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.8, polymorphic-relationship

Suppose I have a `posts`, and `attachments` tables, What I want is to get a specific post, and load its attachments.
Currently, I'm doing this:

```
$post->load([
   'attachments:id,name,original_name,size,mime,category'
]);
```

and it's generated query like this:

```
"query" => "select `id`, `name`, `original_name`, `size`, `mime`, `category` from `attachments` where `attachments`.`attachable_id` in (4) and `attachments`.`attachable_type` = ?"
"bindings" => array:1 [
  0 => "App\Post"
]
```

Above query result is empty, because of not escaping `\`, If I copy, past this query in MySQL workbench and escape that slash like `"App\\Post"` it's working. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution that I can think of that. 
Suppose if you have mapping to change your namespace `App\Post` with `posts` or something like that, which don't need any slashes. I think that is the very helpful.

So Laravel provide us something like this mapping. you can read that on Laravel official documentation. Here is the link- [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types)

Comment: If I add this `Relation::morphMap([
            'users' => 'App\User',
            'businesses' => 'App\Business',
        ]);` to the `boot` function of `AppServiceProvider`, all of auth routes of vuejs redirect me to the `403` page not found